# Javascript Base64 Decoding to Invalid JSON Output

Tags: json, firebase, google-cloud-functions, app-store-connect, server-to-server

I'm using a Firebase Cloud function to receive a JSON payload in an http request from the App Store (server-to-server notifications) that contains a Base64 encoded string. I'm decoding using:

```
const latestReceipt = request.body.latest_receipt ? Buffer.from(request.body.latest_receipt, 'base64').toString() : null;
```

This is works fine in another function to decode a message coming from the Google Play Store. The decoded string coming from Apple, however, is an invalid JSON object.

```
{
"original-purchase-date-pst" = "2019-09-20 16:40:20 America/Los_Angeles";
"quantity" = "1";
"subscription-group-identifier" = "****";
"unique-vendor-identifier" = "****";
"original-purchase-date-ms" = "1569022820000";
"expires-date-formatted" = "2019-09-24 02:55:47 Etc/GMT";
"is-in-intro-offer-period" = "false";
"purchase-date-ms" = "1569293447000";
"expires-date-formatted-pst" = "2019-09-23 19:55:47 America/Los_Angeles";
"is-trial-period" = "false";
"item-id" = "1478806339";
"unique-identifier" = "******";
"original-transaction-id" = "1000000570864027";
"expires-date" = "1569293747000";
"transaction-id" = "1000000571530192";
"bvrs" = "11";
"web-order-line-item-id" = "1000000047099385";
"version-external-identifier" = "0";
"bid" = "****";
"product-id" = "storage_increase";
"purchase-date" = "2019-09-24 02:50:47 Etc/GMT";
"purchase-date-pst" = "2019-09-23 19:50:47 America/Los_Angeles";
"original-purchase-date" = "2019-09-20 23:40:20 Etc/GMT";
}
```

I'm assuming that I'm doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what exactly. I wouldn't expect the App Store to send invalid JSON.

Comment: That message is not Json. Json has `,` as a record seperator. Your message has `;` as a seperator. Json also has `:` as key value seperator's instead of `=`, and it forbids trailing record separators

Comment: The receipt data is in NSDictionary serialization form, not JSON. You need to handle it differently if you want to read the contents. Possibly even a simple string replacement would make it valid JSON: = -> :, ; -> , except the last comma before }

Comment: Thank you @SamiKuhmonen. That's what I needed to know. I knew it wasn't valid JSON, but I'm not familiar enough with how Apple works to know what this is. Before I started doing some String manipulation I wanted to know this was the expected output.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I don't know if this matters to you, but if you post what you said in an answer, I'll mark it as correct.